# MY SQL Like Operator Isn't giving correct results

Tags: mysql, sql

Query the list of CITY names from STATION which have vowels (i.e., a, e, i, o, and u) as both their first and last characters. Your result cannot contain duplicates.

```
select distinct CITY
    from STATION
    where lower(CITY) like '[a e i o u]%[a e i o u]';
```

Im getting Wrong Answer for this code . Plz helping finding the right approach to solve this qtion

Comment: Like doesn't support character range wildcards.  Think regular expressions,.

Comment: You shouldn't have spaces inside the brackets.

Comment: Use RLIKE (REGEXP), not LIKE.

Comment: Hi Bro, please check with this query `select distinct CITY from STATION where lower(CITY) RLIKE '^[AEIOU]' and lower(CITY) RLIKE '[aeiou]$' `

Answer (score 0):

Try Substr() Function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE LOWER(SUBSTR(CITY,1,1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') AND LOWER(SUBSTR(CITY,-1,1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
select distinct CITY from STATION
WHERE LOWER(SUBSTRING(CITY, 1, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') OR LOWER(RIGHT(CITY, 1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
```